# Arduino read 20 bit number from 3 registers

Tags: arduino

I have an ADXL355 (EVAL-ADXL355-PMDZ) that I am trying to test against a very expensive industrial grade sensor.  I am using I2C and I am able to read the device properties and settings as described in the [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL354_355.pdf).

The issue I'm having is how to read the 3 ZDATA (or XDATA, YDATA) registers as a single value.  I have tried two approaches.  Here is the first:

```
double values[3];
Wire.beginTransmission(addr);
  Wire.write(0x08); // ACCEL_XAXIS
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(addr, 9, true); // Read 9, 3 for each axis
  byte x1, x2, x3;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    x3 = Wire.read();
    x2 = Wire.read();
    x1 = Wire.read();
    unsigned long tempV = 0;
    unsigned long value = 0;
    value = x3;
    value <<= 12;
    tempV = x2;
    tempV <<= 4;
    value |= tempV;
    tempV = x1;
    tempV >>= 4;
    value |= tempV;
    values[i] = SCALEFACTOR * value;
  }
```

This will produce values that approach 1g for negative gravity and 3g for positive gravity.  Also the unloaded axes will sometimes show offscale high instead of -0.0g.  They bounce from 0.0 to 4.0 g's.  This tells me I have a sign problem which I'm sure comes from using `unsigned long`.  So I attempted to read it as a 16 bit value and retain the sign.

```
double values[3];
  Wire.beginTransmission(addr);
  Wire.write(0x08); // ACCEL_XAXIS
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(addr, 9, true); // Read 9, 3 for each axis
  byte x1, x2, x3;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    x3 = Wire.read();
    x2 = Wire.read();
    x1 = Wire.read();
    long tempV = 0;
    long value = 0;
    value = x3;
    value <<= 8;
    tempV = x2;
    value |= tempV;
    values[i] = SCALEFACTOR * value;
  }
```

This produced values are good in terms of sign but they are (as expected) much lower in magnitude than they are supposed to be.  I tried to create a 20 bit number like this `long value:20;` but I received

> expected initializer before ':' token

same error for `int`.

How do I properly read from 3 registers to obtain a correct 20 bit value?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing: test this acceleremoeter against expensive ones. I'm having a very bad time because of output values stucked to the selected range, as described also [here](https://ez.analog.com/mems/f/q-a/109925/adxl355-latch-up-condition) by other users. Did you have the same problems with this accelerometer or all went good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you really want to use unsigned types when using the left and right shift operators (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/are-the-shift-operators-arithmetic-or-logical-in-c)).

Taking a look to the [avr-gcc type layout](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Type_Layout) we learn that `long` are represented on 4 bytes (i.e. 32 bits) so they are long enough (no pun intended) to "hold" your 20 bits numbers (XDATA, YDATA, and ZDATA). On the other hand, `int` are represented on 2 bytes (i.e. 16 bits) and thus should not be used in your case.

According to the datasheet you linked page 33, the numbers are formatted as [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Your first example correctly set **the last 20 bits** of your unsigned, 32 bits long `value` (in particular the left justification handling — right-shifting `x1` by four — already looks correct) *but* the "new" 12 most significants bits are always set to `0`.

To perform [sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension), you need to set the "new" 12 most significant bits to `0` if the number is a positive value, `1` if the number is a negative value (adaptation of your first example):

```cpp
...
value |= tempV;
if (x3 & 0x80) /* msb is 1 so the number is a negative value */
    value |= 0xFFF00000;
```

From there, what you should observe is about the same behaviour as previously: high positive values instead of small negative ones (but even higher than previously). This is caused by the fact that while your `value` is correct bitwise speaking, it is still *intepreted* as unsigned. This can be worked around by forcing the compiler to use `value` as signed:

```cpp
values[i] = SCALEFACTOR * (long)value;
```

And now it should be working.

Note that this answer use the fact that your C/C++ implementation use two's complement to represent negative integers. While very rare in practice, the standard allow other representations (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704908/compilers-and-negative-numbers-representations) for examples).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to make it work.  It does use bitshifting on a signed value.  Various sources have said that this is a potential bug as it is implementation defined.  It worked on my platform.

```
typedef union {
  byte bytes[3];
  long value:24;
} accelData;

double values[3];
Wire.beginTransmission(addr);
Wire.write(0x08); // ACCEL_XAXIS
Wire.endTransmission();
Wire.requestFrom(addr, 9, true); // Read 9, 3 for each axis
accelData raw;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
  raw.bytes[2] = Wire.read();
  raw.bytes[1] = Wire.read();
  raw.bytes[0] = Wire.read();
  long temp = raw.value >> 4;
  values[i] = SCALEFACTOR * (double)temp;
}
```

I prefer the solution presented by Alexandre Perrin.

Comment: Also note that this implementation rely on endianess.

Comment: @Alexandre Perrin Your one as well. It is unnecessary bad comment

Comment: @PeterJ As far as I understand, my solution use only bitwise operations which work the same regardless of the endianess (unlike union type-punning). see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041554/bitwise-operators-and-endianness).

Answer (score 0):

```
union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned : 4;
        unsigned long uvalue : 20;
    };
    struct
    {
        unsigned : 4;
        signed long ivalue : 20;
    };
    unsigned char rawdata[3];
}raw;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
  raw.bytes[2] = Wire.read();  //if most significant part is transfered first
  raw.bytes[1] = Wire.read();
  raw.bytes[0] = Wire.read();

  values[i] = SCALEFACTOR * (double)raw.ivalue;
}
```